# Mysql viewing table loaded with file

Tags: mysql

I have table loaded with file in mysql. When trying to view the table with select * from table;

It show scramble over the screen I can’t read it.

How to view the table nicely

Comment: What MySQL client are you using? What do you mean "scrambled?"

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a Database Management System, it is not a reading software. Anyway :) There is a way. It is a strange situation but you can install some sort of ODBC connector for MySQL and connect your Microsoft Word or similar software to that particular table and read it nicely :)

Or, you can create a web application that uses that table as a datasource and read it in your web browser.